# How can I use an initializer list to initialize a 2D vector member?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the code:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>    

class Foo {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
    public:
    Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> > & data) : data(data) {}
};

int main(){
    Foo f {{1,2},{3,3}};
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler complains:

```
initalizer_list_test.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >&)’:
initalizer_list_test.cpp:11:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >::vector(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >&)’
     Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> > & data) : data(data) {}
                                                                               ^
initalizer_list_test.cpp:11:79: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/vector:64:0,
                 from initalizer_list_test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:392:9: note: template<class _InputIterator, class> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&)
         vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:392:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
initalizer_list_test.cpp:11:79: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
     Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> > & data) : data(data) {}
```

How to get it work properly?

Comment: wouldn´t std::initializer_list<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, just use an initializer list of vectors in order to initialize the 2D vector. Then just take it by value instead of by reference (initializer lists, to my knowledge, are normally passed by value and a non-const reference won't work):

```
Foo(std::initializer_list<std::vector<int> > data) : data(data) {}
```

Comment: Doesn't types have to match? How does the compiler know the difference between 1D and 2D with just a 1D-vector of int as initializer type?

Comment: @JonPall, Vectors can be initialized with initializer lists containing their `T`. Thus, `{{1, 2}}` matches an initializer list containing one vector of two elements, which can be used to initialize the member because the list contains `std::vector<int>`, just like the member wants.

Comment: It is still not working. Error: `initalizer_list_test.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >)’:
initalizer_list_test.cpp:11:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >::vector(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >&)’
     Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> > data) : data(data) {}`

Comment: @texasbruce, Interesting, it worked when I tested it with Clang, but the error looks like you didn't change it to `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>` and instead still have an init list of init lists.

Comment: @juanchopanza `gcc -v` gives me `gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC) `

Comment: @texasbruce. lose the ampersand

Comment: @JonPall Look at the error, `In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int> >)’`

Comment: @texasbruce, Precisely, an init list of init lists. It should be an init list of vectors. The matching when calling works great.

Comment: @chris But why an init list of init list does not work?

Comment: @texasbruce, I might be a bit mucky, but the vector's constructor takes a `std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>>`. Such conversions cannot be applied to all elements of the list to change the entire type of the list.